# iPhone app view is cut off at the botton when run on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[image]I need your help. I have designed an app to target iPhone only and everything works fine. However, I just realised that when I run it on iPad, I get black spaces around the screen (view doesn't cover full screen of the iPad) and strangely, the bottom part of the app gets cut off when it runs on iPad. How do I get full screen iPad mode without part of the view getting cut off. Thanks

Comment: Please provide screenshot & little more details..

Comment: @NileshPatel, I have updated my question with a screenshot. See the black spaces around the view. Also there is a button below the "Log in with Facebook" but it is cut off when opened on iPad though. Thanks

Comment: There must be an issue with applying Auto Layout Stuff, Have you tried to run your application on iPhone 4S?

Comment: I just tried it and it showing the same (bottom cut) as it did on the iPad. The only difference is it full screen with no black spaces around. What do you think I can do to sort this out?

Comment: Then you haven't applied a auto layout constraint properly.

Comment: Did you use LaunchScreen.xib?

Comment: @Paruru, I am using Launch Images Source instead of Launch Screen file.

Comment: @Nilesh, I didn't use any constraint, can you help me out on this? Thanks

Comment: What is Devices of target? It should be universal.

Comment: do you know anything about Auto Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour(black spaces around the screen) if the value for "Devices:" under Target/deploymentInfo is set to iPhone. In this case you can still test on iPad but with iPhone resolution. (but if it set to iPad you can not test on iPhone).
if you want to get iPad resolution you have to change "Devices:" value to universal. 
for (bottom cut) check if your code uses device size for positioning buttons.
Your app  must also run on iPad without modification as for 
2.10 App Store Review Guidelines

Comment: Thanks @Idali for the comment. I don't use device size to position the button. I just dragged the button onto storyboard and reposition it using the attribute/property view. However, I coded the position of the facebook button and that is not even causing the problem.

Comment: did you get the same result on device "iPad" and simulator

Comment: Yes @Idali, same results

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to set your the view (on `Main.storyboad`) to fit all size. That is `wAny hAny).
[image]

Then selected the views, add some constrains to them one by one. When you run the app, it should be right. If the position doesn't match your expectation, you can change the constrains. You should know things about `AutoLayout`. Find some article to read, and practise.
[image]

Comment: I have enabled AutoLayout already in my Storyboard file. That doesn't seems to help when opened on iPad

Comment: not just enabled AutoLayout, You need to use it, like adding constrains. read some blog.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks guys for all the comments. Using your comments and reading and testing AutoLayout features, I am able to solve the problem.

Comment: I am not able to solve the similar issue for iphone 4s. Screens look good from iphone 5 onwards.

Comment: Not fair! Recap all answers in your one if you think it's the right!